# How to send response as a multi-part

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jersey, multipart

I have one API in which I have to send a response which contains one binary,

I tried some example from StackOverflow but I did not get any solution.

I tried In **Jersey**

```
   @POST
    @Path("/testmultipart")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("multipart/mixed")
    public Response multipartTest() throws URISyntaxException, MessagingException, IOException 
    {
         File image = new File("C:\\Users\\ganesh\\img\\logo.png");
         MultiPart objMultiPart = new MultiPart();
         objMultiPart.type(new MediaType("multipart", "mixed"));
         objMultiPart.bodyPart(image.getName(), new MediaType("text", "plain"));
         objMultiPart.bodyPart("" + image.length(), new MediaType("text","plain"));
         objMultiPart.bodyPart(image, new MediaType("multipart", "mixed"));
         return Response.ok(objMultiPart).build();
    }
```

But no luck can you please help.

Comment: You can have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50204061/2587435)

Answer (score 1):

**For sending single file:**

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
 public Response multipartTest() {
  File file = new File("C:\\Users\\ganesh\\img\\logo.png");
  return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
      .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"" ) 
      .build();
}
```

There are couple of alternatives to return  zip multi-part response too.

Use below code to send multiple data objects in one go.

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> body
  = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
body.add("firstName", getFirstName());
body.add("images", getImage1());
body.add("images", getImage2());
body.add("lastName", getLastName());

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> entityData
  = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = template
  .postForEntity('endpoinit URL', entityData, String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for single file how to send multiple with some json

Comment: Good, @Ganesh Patil. Please elaborate precisely what kind of object you are trying to return as JSON multi-part response

Comment: I want to send some data like first name, last name and two image file

Comment: @GaneshPatil please go through updated answer

Comment: I haveto send a response with multiple files and some data