# How do I send multipart data (JSON + octet stream) from the server to the client using Jersey?

Tags: json, download, stream, jersey, multipart

There are lots of examples of Jersey code that streams binary data along with some JSON meta information from the client to the server as multipart, but I cannot find ANY examples showing how to do this in the other direction (server to client). Can anyone provide a pointer to such an example? I need to implement both the client and the server side. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Return the same thing on the server side that you would send out on the client side, i.e. a MultiPart/FormDataMultiPart

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50204061/2587435