# RESTful JAX-RS download mutiple pdfs with mutipart request

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, httpresponse

I have a Restful JAX-RS Service which has a GET (`/retrieve-pdfs`) API which should respond with multiple PDF within the JSON response payload.

Example :

```
{
    "response": [{
            "pdf_name": "name_1.pdf",
            "File": "< pdf_data >"
        },
        {
            "pdf_name": "name_2.pdf",
            "File": "< pdf_data >"
        }
    ]
}
```

1. If this is not the valid approach, Can someone let me know the right way to respond multiple pdfs
2. The consumer is a Java application so **Content-Disposition** is not a requirement

Comment: That's not what multipart is. You want to see a [real multipart response example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50204061/2587435)?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible to have a JSON response that includes PDF files.

Also I think it is not possible to download multiple files with just one request. Easiest way will be just but all the files in a *.zip file and than provide the *.zip file.

Here you have an easy example how create a *.zip file: [Zip example](https://www.baeldung.com/java-compress-and-uncompress)

And here a good example how your controller should look like: [Controller example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100936/file-downloading-in-restful-web-services)

Comment: can we have a JSON response with pdf content as an attribute with string format (base encoded)?
Something like {
    "response": [{
            "pdf_name": "name_1.pdf",
            "content": "sgdjnsdgk;..."
        },
        {
            "pdf_name": "name_2.pdf",
            "content": "qwrkr;kmas.."
        }
    ]
}

Comment: If not the JSON what are the other approaches to send multiple pdf as response @Mafick can you please let me know

Comment: Yes, it is quite common to base-64 encode a binary file (like a PDF) and return in JSON.  It makes the JSON harder to read, but it works fine.  Another alternative is to put the file somewhere and return a URL to download it.