# SpringBoot: Send a zip file as an attachment and a JSON body in the same response

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to create a RESTController in a SpringBoot application which will return a zip file as an attachment and a JSON body containing metadata about the zip file, both in the same REST response.

I tried to find examples for Multipart download but most of the examples are about file upload with json body in request. So far I have encountered below post only which seems relevant but does not look elegant as it requires client side specific libraries to receive the response properly.

[Can I send an excel file and JSON body with a description of file in same REST API Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50188321/can-i-send-an-excel-file-and-json-body-with-a-description-of-file-in-same-rest-a)

Is there any elegant way to achieve this in SpringBoot where client side implementation is not required? Any pointers on this is appreciated.

Comment: Response is simple: everything is possible if your client is able to manage what you send. So think the opposite side of your question :  ask yourself how your client can manage 2 object in response of one query. If you manage the client, there is no problem, if you want to use standard client, then you already have your answer : it is not possible.

Comment: @wargre I was hoping if there was any specification by which a standard client (like browser) would understand the content based on its actual type. I guess there's nothing like that.

Comment: In http/2 format, you have a "push" option, BUT there is a catch, it only works for resources a browser manage (css/image ...) here you want json + zip so you have to manage something. At this point you'd better add a data attribute with the base64 file and manage everything on client side.